# Profiling Swift with Instruments, what exactly is _swift_retain_?

Tags: ios, swift, performance, instruments

I'm profiling my Swift iOS app using Instruments. A bunch of time is spent in

```
_swift_retain_(swift::HeapObject*) libSwiftCore.dylib
```

and

```
_swift_release_(swift::HeapObject*) libSwiftCore.dylib
```

My code is mostly creating (and going out of scope) structs and tuples. It's my understand that since they are value objects, they're allocated on the stack, thus I shouldn't be seeing so much heap action.

What exact does `_swift_retain_` and `_swift_release_` mean?

Comment: These functions `_swift_retain_` and `_swift_release_` are part of [Swifts automatic reference counting (ARC)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html). For detailes, see [the source in stdlib](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/swift-2.2-SNAPSHOT-2015-12-01-b/stdlib/public/runtime/HeapObject.cpp). ARC seems to be quite often nagged upon w.r.t. performance issues such as this one, but I'm surprised you see this behaviour using only value types. However, who knows what goes on with ARC behind the hood...

Comment: Hmmm it says "Reference counting only applies to instances of classes", I must have a class that heavily reassigned.

Comment: Yeah that same sentence had me confused over your case, as you say you mainly have value types.

Comment: @dfri if you move your comments to an answer I can mark it as answered

Comment: I added it as a comment mainly because I didn't believe it was thorough enough to be an answer. Anyway, at your request I'll add it below. Possibly someone else catches this thread and can give a more thorough and specific answer.

Comment: You didn't mention what was inside those structs. If they contain objects, then certainly there will be ARC activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These functions `_swift_retain_` and `_swift_release_` are part of [Swifts automatic reference counting (ARC)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html). For detailes, see [the source in stdlib](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/runtime/HeapObject.cpp). ARC seems to be quite often nagged upon w.r.t. performance issues such as this one, but I'm surprised you see this behaviour using only value types. However, possibly this is due to something with ARC behind the hood.